# How can I set the list of approuver for a merge request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am wondering how to set for a MR the list of approuvers by using the API (in EE).

I could not find the information in the documentation :(

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html), you can't. Looks like it is a feature not supported by the API. Maybe because it's only in the EE edition?

Answer (score 0):

I am checked the docs. The CE version is not support approver for merge request. But in my way , I ask the developer assigned to me after they review the merge request code.